# Combinatorial game with floor function

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

Given the number $n$. Two players alternate turns. In each turn player can replace $n$ with $n-1$ or $\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \rfloor$. Player who writes $0$ wins. Decide for which $n$ second player has the winning strategy.

I know Sprague-Grundy function for this game should be periodic but I'm not sure how to determine that period.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, if you want to take the Sprague-Grundy approach, what have you gotten for small values of $n$?

Comment: Second player has winning strategy for $n=3,5,7,12,14,18,20,24,26,28,30,32,34,39,41$

Comment: Have you looked at ternary representations for these numbers? The floor function would just be removing the units digit I think.

Comment: You are completely right but I cannot see how to represent 1 operation in ternary system.

Comment: It’s just subtraction by $1$, but I think I see what you mean that it doesn’t seem to act well with the other operation. How do you know the winning positions are eventually periodic? Is that a guess or do you have a proof?